# Python - call multiple external functions in Class instance

Tags: python

I have a script that watches for changes in file and if occurred it should trigger some actions. Those actions come from two functions defined outside Class. In Class I have defined portion of code to look for changes in file. I cannot figure out how to pass two functions in Class arguments. Here is simplified portion of my script:

```
import time, os

watch_file = 'my_file.txt'

def first_action():
    print('First action called')

def second_action():
    print('Second action called')

class Watcher():
    def __init__(self, watch_file, first_action=None, second_action=None):
        self._cached_stamp = 0
        self.filename = watch_file
        self.first_action = first_action
        self.second_action = second_action

    # Look for changes in 'my_file.txt'
    def look(self):
        stamp = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
        if stamp != self._cached_stamp:
            self._cached_stamp = stamp
            # File has changed, so do something...
            print('File changed')
            if self.first_action is not None:
                print('Call first action')
                self.first_action(self)
            if self.second_action is not None:
                print('Call second action')
                self.second_action(self)    


watcher = Watcher(watch_file, first_action(), second_action())
```

Doing it like above calls `first_action()` and `second_action()` but not inside Class. I know it because I dont see printed 'Call first action' or 'Call second action'
I was able to correctly trigger first action with below code:

```
watch_file = 'my_file.txt'

def first_action():
    print('First action called')

def second_action():
    print('Second action called')

class Watcher():
    def __init__(self, watch_file, first_action=None, *args):
        self._cached_stamp = 0
        self.filename = watch_file
        self.first_action = first_action
        self.args = args

    # Look for changes in 'my_file.txt'
    def look(self):
        stamp = os.stat(self.filename).st_mtime
        if stamp != self._cached_stamp:
            self._cached_stamp = stamp
            # File has changed, so do something...
            print('File changed')
            if self.first_action is not None:
                print('Call first action')
                self.first_action(*self.args)    


watcher = Watcher(watch_file, first_action)
```

For some reason I need to specify `*args` even for function which does not take any argument on call. Can someone explain why `*args` must be used?

Comment: Typo. You mean `watcher = Watcher(watch_file, first_action, second_action)`. Note that I'm not calling the functiosns.

Comment: You want to pass the functions themselves, not the return value of calling them. `Watcher(watch_file, first_action, second_action)`.

Comment: I have already tried that and I only get "first_action" plus some error (see comment in DerHamm answer)

Answer (score 1):

You did it right in the init, but not in the call of "Watcher". To pass the function itself, instead of it's return value, you have to remove the braces.

```
watcher = Watcher(watch_file, first_action, second_action)
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: I have already tried that and I only get "first_action" plus some error:
```File changed
Call first action
Unhandled error: <class 'TypeError'>
File changed
Call first action
Unhandled error: <class 'TypeError'>```